# Why can't I remove the empty string in this list?

Tags: python

I know this is a rather trivial question, but that's why I thought too when I was trying to solve it. Yet, I am here and asking this question. It should be very easy and probably I am doing something completely wrong, but I'd like to know what I am doing wrong.

I have this list of strings:

```
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '6', ' ', '6', ' ', '5', ' ', '6', ' ', '5']
```

I've stripped the /n already by doing this:

```
rstrip("\n")
```

And now, I want to get rid of the empty strings, so I tried to use `filter(None,x)`, but this isn't working. Also, tried to remove it with a `for loop`; also didn't work.

```
filter(None, the_list)
```

What is wrong with this statement? I also tried this wrapping it into `list()`, but didn't work either.

Also tried this:

```
my_list = [str for str in the_list if str]
```

Am I missing something?

*PS: my ultimate goal is to convert the strings into ints so that I can calculate stuff, but I can only that if I get rid of the empty strings.*

Comment: Your strings are not empty. They contain a space each.

Comment: your strings have spaces between them, remove them & try again.

Comment: That didn't work @Chris_Rands. Thanks for the info guys, I don't know why this is downvoted, but I am just a rookie who didn't see the obvious part. Sorry for that, just trying to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have empty strings. You have strings with one space in each.

You can remove those by testing if they are empty after stripping:

```
my_list = [el for el in the_list if el.strip()]
```

However, you may want to examine how you got that list in the first place. Perhaps you can strip out those spaces earlier, or use `str.split()` without an argument to split on *arbitrary width* whitespace rather than on a fixed-width string.

Comment: I will accept this answer, because you have pointed me in the right direction, by saying that I should have stripped the spaces in the first place. I know now what I did wrong! Thank you Martijn!

Comment: Any notable difference between using `if el.strip()` vs `if not el.isspace()` or just style preference?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: `el.strip()` has to return a new string object, `el.isspace()` only a boolean. Since I generally process strings before this point I didn't think of `el.isspace()`. For ASCII text `el.strip()` is optimised however, so for a single space the difference is very small indeed (perhaps 10-20% speed difference, but this is only going to be noticeable at 100 million repetitions, because both are so very fast.

Answer (score 8):

You don't have empty strings but strings containing whitespace(s). You can use [`str.isspace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) to filter out the unwanted strings:

```
s = ['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '6', ' ', '6', ' ', '5', ' ', '6', ' ', '5']

r = [i for i in s if not i.isspace()]
print(r)
# ['1', '2', '6', '6', '5', '6', '5']
```

Answer (score 4):

This strings is not empty, there are whitespaces in it.
Use strip()

```
[str for str in l if str.strip()]
```

Answer (score 2):

A string containing space is not an empty string. You can delete these strings which only contains space by:

```
[si for si in sl if si.strip()]
```

Comment: Add possible novelty to you answer. This is an exact copy of (currently) three other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they are not empty strings but are whitespaces

```
l = [x for x in l if x.strip()]
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter(None, my_list)` only remove empty item, but your item contains space which is not empty. Try below

```
my_list = ['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '6', ' ', '6', ' ', '5', ' ', '6', ' ', '5']
my_list = filter(lambda x:x.strip(), my_list)
# ['1', '2', '6', '6', '5', '6', '5']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ' ' in my_list:
    my_list.remove(' ')
```

`filter` will not work, because `' '` is not empty, i.e., not `None`.

Comment: Thank you! @gustafbstrom

Answer (score 0):

```
for num in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[num] == " ":
        try:
            my_list.pop(num)
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Not very efficient but works aha